# Bootstrap button not staying within div?

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I'm trying to make a bootstrap button resize if the text within it is too long.

At the moment it is sticking out the other end of the div and looks silly.

Here's my code:

```
<div class="row marketing">

    <div class="col-lg-7">

        <video id="video_player" class="video-js vjs-default-skin" autoplay preload="auto" width="100%" poster="http://video-js.zencoder.com/oceans-clip.png" data-setup="{}">
              <source src="http://video-js.zencoder.com/oceans-clip.mp4" type='video/mp4' />
              <track kind="captions" src="demo.captions.vtt" srclang="en" label="English"></track>
        </video>

    </div>

    <div class="col-lg-5">

      <div class="list-group">
          <a href="#" class="list-group-item"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-ok-sign"></span> Cras justo odio</a>
          <a href="#" class="list-group-item"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-ok-sign"></span> Dapibus ac facilisis in</a>
          <a href="#" class="list-group-item"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-ok-sign"></span> Morbi leo risus</a>
          <a href="#" class="list-group-item"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-ok-sign"></span> Porta ac consectetur ac</a>
          <a href="#" class="list-group-item"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-ok-sign"></span> Vestibulum at eros</a>
      </div>

      <a class="btn btn-lg btn-success" href="#">Donec id elit non mi porta gravida at eget metus.</a>

    </div>

  </div>
```

Thanks,
Andy

Comment: Appears to work here with your current code. http://bootply.com/88852

Comment: Hi Josh, yeah sorry, it is nesting within another container on my page which is 900px. I would like the button to keep within the <div class=col-lg-5>.

Answer (score 2):

I had the same problem. I solved it by setting the CSS property:

```
white-space:normal
```

because Bootstrap has it on default as `nowrap`